# usage of variables in different classes in Java

Tags: java

I don't understand the int a; in the main that I called st in the Action listener. I want the st to decrease for 1 everytime a cetain button is clicked but it seems to work separetly for each button. I made it so it writes it out on a button each time I press another button to test it and it only works for the first button and then it just stays the same. (I hope I'm making any sense)

Here is my code, Main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Start {
public static int a;
public static JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[15][15];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame okno = new JFrame("Nonogram");
    okno.setVisible(true);
    okno.setSize(700, 700);
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    okno.add(panel);

    JPanel polje = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15, 15));
    panel.add(polje, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            if (i < 5 && j < 5) {
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                // gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
            } else if (i < 5 || j < 5) {
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                // gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                gumbi[i][j].setEnabled(false);

            } else {
                if (Math.random() <= 0.6) {

                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("3");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);

                } else {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("4");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                }
            }
            if (gumbi[i][j].getText() == "3") {
                a += 1;
            }
            if (i == 14 && j == 14) {
                gumbi[i][j].setText("" + a);

            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

and ActionListener:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Listener implements ActionListener {
JButton[][] gumbi = Start.gumbi;
int st = Start.a;

public Listener(JButton[][] gumbi)  {
    this.gumbi = gumbi;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    JButton gumb = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE && gumb.getText() == "3"){
        st -= 1;

    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK && gumb.getText() == "3"){
        st += 1;
        gumbi[0][0].setText("" + st);
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you created a copy of the Static Variable(Start.a) to the instance variable (st), which will be individual copy for each instance of action listener.

If you really need to maintain the value at class level , why not manipulate the value directly rather keeping a copy.

```
if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE && gumb.getText() == "3"){
    Start.a -= 1;

} else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK && gumb.getText() == "3"){
    Start.a += 1;
    gumbi[0][0].setText("" + st);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
int st = Start.a;
```

isn't doing what you think. It's reading the value of `a` when the instance is created, and *copying* its value into a new variable `st`. Changing `st` won't have any effect on `a` because you're only changing a copy; and you've got a new copy for each instance that you create.

Try changing `Start.a` directly, rather than copying it into a new `st` and changing that.